# command line tools for various internet services

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a set of tools to consume various internet services from the command line: i.e. internet search, check the weather, check stocks, email, facebook, twitter, news/rss, etc.?

Thanks

Comment: I think your question is too broad. There is not really an all-in-one solution, I think, (unless you want to hear "just use a browser"). Therefore I'd recommend you to split up your question and ask separately for each thing. Also don't forget to add some detail about what exactly you want and expect from the tool.

Comment: I understand one can find a tool for each particular task. I also understand you can use a browser, but it is inconvenient. I'm mostly asking for a "set" that someone created or compiled.

Comment: You maybe able to compile your own list with the help of this series of videos starting with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t01raGC8m2M. There've been other "30 day challenges" by other Linux users with the focus being on getting most everything done in the terminal. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that we use plain/dumb terminal as on <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd>.

You can use console/terminal web-browsers:

- `elinks` ([*advanced text-mode WWW browser*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/elinks));
- `links` ([*Web browser running in text mode*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/links));
- `links2` ([*Web browser running in both graphics and text mode*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/links2));
- `lynx` ([*classic non-graphical (text-mode) web browser*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/lynx)).

You can use console e-mail clients:

- `alpine` ([*Text-based email client, friendly for novices but powerful*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/alpine));
- `mutt` ([*text-based mailreader supporting MIME, GPG, PGP and threading*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mutt));

You can use console RSS-clients:

- `rsstail` ([*console RSS reader that monitors a feed and outputs new entries*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/rsstail));
- `olive` ([*console RSS reader*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/olive)).

You can view weather forecast with:

- `ansiweather` ([*Weather in your terminal, with ANSI colors and Unicode symbols*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ansiweather)).